# MKS integrity client get folder structure

Tags: client, integrity, mks-integrity

I have a project folder in integrity client from which I want to get the entire folder structure. This folder structure should have all the folders and subfolders but no files inside. I don't even know this is possible or not.

I want this to run from command line. Any suggestion from UI perspective is also fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can't be achieved with only one command;

my suggestion is to createa a small script or batch, where you will use the `SI VIEWPROJECT --RECURSE` command and filter out the lines not ending with ".pj" (subprojects)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm much too late, but I just stumbled across your question.

You could use the following command (simply type into Windows command line) to inventarize a downloaded sandbox:

```
$ TREE /F <path to Sandbox>
```

So in my case it'd be:

```
$ TREE /F D:\Sandbox\Name
```

You could even guide the output into a .txt file and postprocess it from there...

```
$ TREE /F D:\Sandbox\Name > D:\Output.txt
```

Edit: You would still have to take out all the filenames afterwards in your favourite programming language of choice (just check for the dash characters in front of folders and delete everything else...)

Comment: (Note: The solution above should also work on UNIX systems... As far as I know you would have to install "tree" first though... using `apt` for example.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `si viewproject` command with `filter` by name activated to get only subprojects.

```
si viewproject --hostname={SI_HOST} --port={SI_PORT} --project={Project_Path} --filter=attribute:name=project.pj -R
```

Depends on your server configuration, the `project.pj` can be different.